# Retriving specific Windows event logs after a certain date using C#

Tags: c#, windows, date, events, logging

I want to retrieve all windows event logs created after a certain date, I was wondering how to do it with an if condition.  This loop just prints all the dates/time values present in the Application log

```
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in demolog.Entries)
        {
            DateTime errorTime = entry.TimeGenerated;
            Console.WriteLine("Error Time is " + errorTime);
        }
```

The date are time are stored together in the event logger: yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss AM/PM.  I have no idea how to compare dates.  Just need some ideas.  Thanks

Comment: So basically you are asking about how to compare dates in C# right? Probably your title should be adopted to be a bit more precise regarding your actual question.

Comment: You can compare `DateTime` the same way you compare `int`: `if(oneDateTime > someOtherDateTime)`. This would be the very first thing to try, so what problems did you run into?